# Connecting to / view contents of Recycle Bin with ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog, windows-7

Can you connect ArcCatalog to the Recycle Bin on the desktop?

I deleted (not using ArcCatalog) a folder which contained several shapefiles and .gpx files for a non-work related project that I thought I would never need again, but unfortunately I may have to track it down. These shapefiles are unique enough that I would be able to recognize it using the Preview window in ArcCatalog.

From what I have  [read](https://superuser.com/questions/556333/which-folder-is-recycle-bin-in-on-win7-how-to-check-files-there) , the Recycle Bin is a hidden directory but there are ways to show what is within the directory. I am able to connect to c:\$Recycle.Bin using ArcCatalog, but it appears to be empty and I am not sure how happy the IT department would be if I did what was recommended in that link.

It is possible to create a new folder and drag the folders from the Recycle Bin into it and search that way, but I have a feeling I may need to do this a few more times in the future due to reckless file deletion in the past. Also, many of the folders have the same name, and some of the folders within the Recycle Bin are massive, so it would be a time consuming process.

---

By doing what the article suggested and making the Recycle Bin and its contents visible in Windows Explorer, making a connection to the Recycle Bin in ArcCatalog, then making the Recycle Bin not visible again, the connection to the Recycle Bin in ArcCatalog remained.

Comment: There is an existing, and Deferred, [ArcGIS Idea for an ArcCatalog Recycle Bin](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=0873000000087Ye) that you may wish to vote for.  Another Q&A here that may be worth you reviewing is http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107860/how-to-un-delete-a-folder-accidentally-deleted-in-arccatalog

Comment: Fortunately, I am sure the folder was not deleted using ArcCatalog, so I know it is still around and hiding somewhere in the Recycle Bin.

Comment: Moving it out of the recycle bin to a new 'temp' folder is probably your best bet and definitely the safest. Keep in mind the recycle bin can empty itself based on time or allocated space, so it's possible that it may have been overwritten by newer deletions or sitting in there too long. I see nothing in your link that would make IT unhappy unless they've already locked you down from doing it.

Comment: A major ESRI gripe of mine for a decade. Why when something is deleted in ArcCatalog does it no go to the (or a) Recycle Bin!

Comment: @usertwoseventwothreenine I think that depends more on what it is, specifically the format it's in. Catalog isn't just a *file* browser, but it's also a *database* browser. Actually it's not really a file browser either - when you look at a shapefile you only see a single file, not the components. It similarly allows you to 'browse' to the worksheets in a spreadsheet, or bands in an image - something Explorer does not. Putting GIS aside, would you expect a table in a 'regular' database (ie Access) to go to the recycle bin if deleted? Because that's the same principle with feature classes, etc.

Comment: Are you suggesting a Feature Class could not go into an ArcCatalog Recycle Bin? Seems lacking in imagination. Are you suggesting a DB connection could not reside in an ArcCatalog Recycle Bin? Seems lacking in imagination to me.  Your analogies are off. The MS Access example would be against an mdb (not the tables within the mdb) and the parts of a shapefile. So yes in this example I would expect the core containing file (the mdb) to go into a recycle bin if I pressed delete in explorer, and it does. I should also point out the GIS community shares my view about 100 to 1.

Comment: @usertwoseventwothreenine A feature class is a series of tables in a database. The database can be stored as one file (.mdb) or each table/index/etc. as separate files like a file geodatabase (.gdb). A shapefile is another file-based database - Catalog treats it as such, showing a single entry. I'm not suggesting a Catalog Recycle Bin or linking it to the system is a bad idea, nor that the current delete behavior makes sense *in all cases* because it doesn't. Especially when it *looks* like a file browser. I'm not sure why you've taken the comment personally and responded with insults.

Comment: @ChrisW, No insults in the response. It would be flagged by now if it had them. Can you point one out? Thanks, I know fully how both file and personal geodatabase work as well as shapefiles. You seem to have a misunderstanding of shapefiles if you think they are  databases in any modern meaning of the word. This link may help clear it up for you. http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf None of what you said removes the possibility of an ArcCatlaog form of recycle. Indeed it is one of the most popular suggestion on the ESRI ideas list. Ill post the link for you.

Comment: @ChrisW, actually PolyGEO also posted it already. http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=0873000000087Ye

Comment: @usertwoseventwothreenine Well, flags *are* appearing. Your statements about "lacking in imagination" seem to be personally directed at ChrisW; they don't speak to the issue at hand. That's contrary to [site policy](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), which I urge you to review at the earliest opportunity.  Please keep the conversation civil.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to do what you want, but I would suggest turning on the [System Protection](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-is-system-protection) capability on Windows. It's saved me a couple times.

If the folder you deleted was inside another folder, right click on it and check the Previous Versions tab. Find an older date and click on the Open button.

[image]

Maybe you'll get lucky and System Protection was on (which might be default).